# Cisco L3 switch two default routes config

Tags: cisco, routing, switch

I have L3 switch connected to `ISP1`, and recently i got new link from `ISP2` for few special host going to use that new route. How i am going to tell switch two send traffic for special host to new `ISP2` network and rest `ISP1`?

What would be the best configuration to handle this kind of scenarios?

Comment: Are these special hosts going to need to communicate with other hosts on your network? Do they only need to communicate with certain addresses on the new ISP? Will they be on their own VLAN? You need to get into a little more detail.

Comment: Yes, other existing host may need to talk.. for monitoring, management etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had you read about route policies?? That is a kind of configuration to avoid the routing table, and is applied on the in-interfaces, on the way to match the source address of the packet, and do what you want, in this case, sended to an specific "next-hop".

Comment: Cool! got it what your trying to say.. `PBR` Here is the ref: link if anybody else want to do http://howdoesinternetwork.com/2013/configuration-of-pbr-policy-based-routing

Comment: Yeah, PBR is it!!!